# Shop product structured data, does it need a certain product image aspect ratio or size?

Tags: seo, rich-snippets, structured-data, json-ld, google-rich-snippets-tool

I am building an online shop for a client and I was taking a look at google's info in regards to the "product" structured data.

I noticed in their article they specify to point to a product picture ( of course ) but in their examples they specified to use 16/9 4/3 or 1/1 images. Is this a rule for the product image to be used in rich snippets ? I cannot seem to find any information online in regards to this.

My client has product images of 1400px x 1600px so they are not the specified aspect ratio.

In addition to this, when I test the page code with Google's Rich Snippet testing tool everything looks good, there are no errors and it says my page is ok. But when I press the preview button it does not seem to work. It only displays the following error:

Your search - previewid:8db79257-4b04-42ef-93f7-bc27ecad2ecf - did not match any documents.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you